# FAQ Section Working Draft

Tags: discussion, proposed-faq

One of the [7 essential meta question of every beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) is the question what the FAQ should contain.

We should clearly, but succinctly define which questions are on-topic here and which questions would be off-topic. We obviously haven't settled those questions really right now, but we should be able to come up with some first draft of our FAQ.

We have a [default FAQ with the desciption pulled from the Area 51 proposal](https://biology.stackexchange.com/faq) right now. The part of the FAQ we can change is only the first section "What kind of questions can I ask here?", this part right now only contains

> **What kind of questions can I ask here?**
>
> Biology - Stack Exchange is for active researchers, academics, and
>   students.

What should our FAQ contain?

Comment: We can now start to put our FAQ into place, so I'd encourage everyone to edit and comment on the answer below =)

Answer (score 5):

## What kind of questions can I ask here?

#### What is on topic?

Generally, most questions relating to the field of biology are acceptable.  Here are some further pointers:

- Medical questions are acceptable providing that they are only discussing the  biological effects of the condition or treatment. *Medical questions should be "how does this work" rather than "what should I do"*. [[source]](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42/where-do-we-draw-the-line-for-questions-about-medicine)
- Questions about bioinformatics and closely related subjects are accepted *as long as* they are addressing the biological aspect of the subject. [[source]](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19/should-bioinformatics-related-questions-be-considered-off-topic)

#### What not to ask:

- Questions on morality and ethics
- Questions of a personal nature

**Please see these [tips on writing a good question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting.**

Comment: We can only edit the first section of the FAQ "What kind of Questions can I ask here?", the rest of the FAQ is static. The parts about what is on-topic/off-topic in your list is a good start, the other topics are pretty much already in the [FAQ](http://biology.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: @MadScientist - Ah, ok. I'll remove those parts and leave the "what can be asked".

Comment: I clarified the question , I forgot that most people aren't familiar with how the FAQ stuff works on a new site.

Comment: "Appropriate tags must be used. If a user is not sure what tags  to use, they should ask on meta." -- wouldn't it be easier to just ask the question, and let someone (who also can create tags) retag it?

Comment: @TimN - I agree with you. I actually meant that we should discourage wildly inappropriate tag usage.

Comment: One thing worth adding would be a clause to tag homework questions as such.

Comment: I propose to add "This would include using bioinformatics tools and understanding the principles behind those tools." from http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19/should-bioinformatics-related-questions-be-considered-off-topic to the bioinformatics section.

Comment: We should really get this on the FAQ page, at least as an interim solution until there are more votes.

Comment: n.b I assume that the [sources] will be stripped out in the live version

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to formulate a draft we could use for our FAQ, I used the already existing FAQs on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq) and [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq), as well as the other post on this question as inspiration.

> **What kind of questions can I ask here?**
>
> Biology - Stack Exchange is for people studying biology at any level.  Questions are from students, academics and active researchers in biology and closely
>   related fields, including:
>
> - general questions about biological concepts
> - questions about the biological mechanisms behind medical conditions
> - questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory
>
> Questions on interdisciplinary subjects like bioinformatics are also
>   welcome, as long as they focus on the biological part of the subject.
>
> **What questions are off-topic?**
>
> - personal medical questions
> - philosophical or ethical questions related to biology
>
> **Please see these [tips on writing a good question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting**.

The FAQ should be reasonably short, it should only cover the most important aspects that are unique to our site. A lot of general rules are already in the other sections of the FAQ, this part is mainly for giving new users a broad overview on what is on-topic and what off-topic on our site.

Feel free to propose additions or changes to this draft.

Comment: Although this version is shorter and possibly more succinct, I think the other answer is more inviting to read. Breaking the advice down into subheadings promotes readability.

Comment: Looking at the Physics and Math FAQs, I wouldn't read those as a new user. I think that's partly to do with the site design making the text too dense, which is off-putting.

Comment: @RichardSmith I changed it a bit to break it into sections,

Comment: I now propose we merge the best parts of the two answers, basically keeping your answer, but adding the link to tips on asking a good question, and changing 'general questions about biological concepts' to 'questions about biological concepts' (as people can ask specific questions too)

Comment: @RichardSmith sounds good

Comment: Maybe a bullet point about programming questions? http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/a/20/576