# Questions on medical science belong here or on health beta?

Tags: discussion

I had recently asked a question on the biological basis of the Jendrassik's maneuver which is performed to reinforce reflexes. This question was migrated to stack [health beta](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/7392/how-does-the-jendrassiks-manoeuvre-reinforce-reflexes). As a medical student and I understand that medical science although applied, is basically.. biology. The questions on health beta seem to be more like patients or hypochondriacs asking health questions, willing to get to know about the treatment they are undertaking and all that, rather than medical students asking biology/medicine.

I personally started on stack with health beta and realised that neither the questions seem to be the biology seeking, nor was there any proper response and then realising stack biology to be a more suited platform.

Although I can find one [old meta post](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/why-are-medical-questions-inherently-off-topic-here) on this, I feel this needs to be discussed.

Answer (score 5):

Questions on medical science are on-topic here as long as they are not about medical advice. However, this is also one area where Health.SE and Biology.SE have some overlap and there are no clearly defined boundaries.

Your question seemed to be about a medical procedure and I know that there are some active users in Health.SE who are experts in medicine. I migrated your post to Health.SE, thinking that the probability of it fetching an answer may be higher over there. It is on-topic here and if Health.SE rejects the migration then we can reopen it.

---

> The questions on health beta seem to be more like patients or
>   hypochondriacs asking health questions, willing to get to know about
>   the treatment they are undertaking and all that, rather than medical
>   students asking biology/medicine.

Well, that is something that even Health.SE considers off-topic.